# How to make a dropdown show values from top instead of where I left it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

On my web form application, I have shown a dashboard with six boxes each with a separate dropdown showing values from a database table. This is for my user's ease of accessibility as they will choose approximately six menu items which they visit most frequently. The dropdown is working fine and show the selected menu items appropriately.

However, the problem is that none of the dropdown show values afresh as it must be. Because once a value is selected from it or just the mouse is scrolled down on it without making any selection, it remember that position. Now when that first dropdwon is revisited again either after selecting a value from another dropdown or just scrolling down the mouse on that another dropdown, the position of the first dropdown remain exactly where it was left before.

I want each and every dropdown to show values from its top and not where user left it before. The code is available here.

```
//
//
//Menu items are taken from database

if (obj.data.length > 0) {
var lielm = '';

var AccountantHeader = false;
var ReportHeader = false;
var OtherHeader = false;

var accountantItems = [];
var reportsItems = [];
var otherItems = [];

$.each(obj.data, function (i, m) {

if (m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Report Financial' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Cover Sheet' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Letters' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Invites')
{
   accountantsItems.push(m);
}

else if (m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Income Statement' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Balance' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Income' || m.Menu_Item_Name == 'Ledger')
 {
    reportsItems.push(m);
 }

else
{
   otherItems.push(m);
}

});

  $.each(accountantItems, function (index, m) {
      if (!AccountantHeader) {
         lielm += '<li class="no-hover"><strong>Accountants</strong></li>';
         AccountantHeader = true;
    }
    lielm += '<li data-value="' + m.Menu_URL + '" title="' + m.Menu_Item_Name.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '') + '">' + m.Menu_Item_Name + '</li>';
 });

$.each(reportsItems, function (index, m) {
    if (!ReportHeader) {
        lielm += '<li class="no-hover"><strong>Reports</strong></li>';
        ReportHeader = true;
      }
    lielm += '<li data-value="' + m.Menu_URL + '" title="' + m.Menu_Item_Name.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '') + '">' + m.Menu_Item_Name + '</li>';
  });

$.each(otherItems, function (index, m) {
       if (!OtherHeader) {
          lielm += '<li class="no-hover"><strong>Other</strong></li>';
          OtherHeader = true;
        }
       lielm += '<li data-value="' + m.Menu_URL + '" title="' + m.Menu_Item_Name.replace('<strong>', '').replace('</strong>', '') + '">' + m.Menu_Item_Name + '</li>';
     });


$(edt).next('.dropdownContain').children('.dropOut').children('.widget-options').html(lielm);
$(edt).next('.dropdownContain').children('.dropOut').children('.widget-options').children('li').click(function () {
var pId = $(edt).parent().parent().attr('id');

var mId = $('#' + pId + ' .menu-id').val() || 0;
var mnu = { UserId: uId, Name: this.outerText, Url: $(this).data('value'), ID: mId }

//
//
// Update dashboard
```

Here is the HTML belong to just a single box (one out of the six sections I have made for dropdowns)

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="box" id="box0">
                            <div class="drop">
                                <div class="edit"><span><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></span></div>     
                                <div class="dropdownContain">
                                    <div class="dropOut">
                                        <div class="triangle"></div>
                                        <ul class="widget-options">                                 
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <a class="menu-href" href="javascript:">
                                <input type="hidden" class="menu-id" />
                                <span class="menu-icon fa fa-2x">&nbsp;</span>
                                <div class="clearfx"></div>
                                <label class="menu-text">&nbsp;</label>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

Any help in this regard will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Providing the html code would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Cata I have just updated the question a little, but the whole logic need to be handled in the code provided earlier.